# iframe resize cross domain no control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have read several articles and tried some methods, but no results.
What I need to do is resize the height of iframe tag on the parent dynamically.
I can't modify the page I put on the iframe src, as it is an application on the intranet in another server.

I know there are security issues, but I need this functionality on the page, as the app should show seamless on the intranet webpage.
I would like to see options, methods or workarounds to achieve this.

I also tried to resize the iframe based on the scroball, but no luck.

Anyone can help me.

Comment: you should be able to modify the height of the <iframe> tag via jQuery with no issues.

Comment: i once solved this with easyxdm, that was easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent:

http://jsbin.com/ujAqemI/1/edit

```
function handleMessage(e) {
  if (e.data.action == 'resize') {
    var targetHeight = e.data.height;
    $('#iFrame').animate({
      height: targetHeight
    });
  }
}
window.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);
```

The iframe:

http://jsbin.com/azUWIye/1/edit

```
parent.postMessage({
  'action':'resize', 
   'height': 400
}, '*');
```

Comment: I the postmessage method, I had to ask the owner of the app to ad code in their app.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the height attribute using jQuery easily enough.
code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
<script>
function ChangeIframeHeight()
{
$('#iframename').attr('height', "900")  //Changes the "height" attribute to 900
}
<body>
<iframe src = "http://google.com" height = "600" width = "900"></iframe> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This won't resize the iframe dynamically, which is an important part of the question.